# SVN - export changes only

Tags: svn, teamcity

We have two SVN repo's, one at our office, one at our clients office. They are using Microsoft TMG proxy/firewall, and for the love of god we cannot get TeamCity/Tortoise/SlikSVN to connect to our repo via the proxy etc - we have literally tried everything we can possibly think of, or find on Google.

Therefore, the only other approach we can think off, is to have SVN at our office, export, FTP it up/down, and then at the clients office import the exported SVN package. The only issue is that I know a dump will export everything (and will be huge), and I'm not sure what other options there are. It's a horrid solution, but TMG seems to have killed off any other options.

Can anyone advise on the SVN options available? Ideally, we want to export the DIFF between the previous revision, or revisions, I guess..... Or, more accurately, the DIFF between NOW and the previous export.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this uber horrid solution?

Many thanks
dotdev

Comment: Will you make changes and commit them on your client's office?

Comment: Repository on office-border host?

Comment: Hi - I'll not commit to the clients office, just to ours, and then somehow ship the changes over to the repo at the clients office.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svn diff --patch-compatible`.

This will generate out a patch compatible diff between the two revisions. You can then apply the patch to a checked out working directory to make it match your copy.

Be careful. This doesn't include property changes

> No-no... Never use --patch-compatible for cross-repository transmits. Only --git and svn patch on other side

---

## Addendum

Shows you how often I do this. The `svn patch` command was added in 1.7 and replaces the use of patching Subversion directly with `svn diff --patch-compatble` output.

According to the SVN Book, the [svn patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html) command says:

> Apply a simple patch file generated by the `svn diff` command. [As an example O]ur patch file  will create a new file, delete another file, and *modify a third's contents and properties*.

So, this command will also apply properties too. That's good to know.

Comment: No-no... **Newer** use `--patch-compatible` for cross-repository transmits. Only `--git` and `svn patch` on other side

Comment: Hi LazyBadger (great name) - could you expand on your comment? What's the difference between your comment and David's suggestion?

Comment: @LazyBadger That `svn patch` is a new command on me. It was apparently added in 1.7. You're right. It's a better way to apply patches on SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make sync both repos at the level of the file system. Don't forget to commit to only one repo before synchronization